# m3u8 file not playing in Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-mediaplayer, android-source

I am trying to playback a m3u8 file in Android Emulator.
`http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8`

It's not able to playback the video but audio is heard.
I get the following error `E/OMXNodeInstance( 39): OMX_GetExtensionIndex failed`.

I traced the calls and I see that the video decoder is not instantiated properly,
I find that `OMXNodeInstance::enableGraphicBuffers` is getting called and that calls,
`OMX_ERRORTYPE err = OMX_GetExtensionIndex(...,const_cast<OMX_STRING>("OMX.google.android.index.enableAndroidNativeBuffers"),...);`
which is then calling `OMX_ERRORTYPE SoftOMXComponent::getExtensionIndex`,
but there is no implementation for this function.
It just returns UndefinedError (code below)

```
OMX_ERRORTYPE SoftOMXComponent::getExtensionIndex(const char *name, OMX_INDEXTYPE *index)
{
return OMX_ErrorUndefined;
}
```

Can somebody please help me to overcome this GetExtentionIndex failure.
Log Below

```
/ChromiumHTTPDataSource( 39): connect to http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear4/prog_index.m3u8 @0
V/NuPlayer( 39): scanning sources haveAudio=0, haveVideo=0
V/NuPlayer( 39): in instantiateDecoder at 693 audio = 0 
V/NuPlayer( 39): in instantiateDecoder at 693 audio = 1 
I/ESQueue ( 39): found AAC codec config (22050 Hz, 1 channels)
I/avc_utils( 39): found AVC codec config (192 x 144, Baseline-profile level 1.1)
V/MediaPlayer( 583): in getCurrentPosition at : 425
V/MediaPlayerService( 39): getCurrentPosition
V/MediaPlayerService( 39): [1] getCurrentPosition = 0
V/NuPlayer( 39): scanning sources haveAudio=0, haveVideo=0
V/NuPlayer( 39): in instantiateDecoder at 701 mime = video/avc
V/ACodec ( 39): Now uninitialized
V/ACodec ( 39): Now uninitialized
V/ACodec ( 39): onAllocateComponent
I/MediaPlayerService( 39): MediaPlayerService::getOMX()
V/SoftOMXPlugin( 39): makeComponentInstance 'OMX.google.h264.decoder'
V/SoftOMXPlugin( 39): makeComponentInstance at 106 
V/ACodec ( 39): onAllocateComponent
I/MediaPlayerService( 39): MediaPlayerService::getOMX()
V/SoftOMXPlugin( 39): makeComponentInstance at 128 
V/SoftOMXPlugin( 39): makeComponentInstance 'OMX.google.aac.decoder'
V/SoftOMXPlugin( 39): makeComponentInstance at 106 
V/SoftOMXPlugin( 39): makeComponentInstance at 128 
V/ACodec ( 39): [OMX.google.h264.decoder] Now Loaded
V/ACodec ( 39): onConfigureComponent
V/ACodec ( 39): configureCodec at 870 
V/ACodec ( 39): setupVideoDecoder at 1400 
V/ACodec ( 39): setupVideoDecoder at 1402 mime = video/avc 
V/ACodec ( 39): setupVideoDecoder at 1406 
V/ACodec ( 39): setupVideoDecoder at 1414 
V/ACodec ( 39): setupVideoDecoder at 1421 
V/ACodec ( 39): setupVideoDecoder at 1429 
V/ACodec ( 39): setupVideoDecoder at 1437 
V/ACodec ( 39): initNativeWindow at 1962 
V/ACodec ( 39): initNativeWindow at 1967 
E/OMXNodeInstance( 39): OMX_GetExtensionIndex failed
V/OMXNodeInstance( 39): enableGraphicBuffers at 301 OMX_GetExtensionIndex returned 2147487745
V/ACodec ( 39): onStart
V/ACodec ( 39): [OMX.google.h264.decoder] Now Loaded->Idle
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it in real device, as I know emulators with some specific sdk's(like 3.1) crash playing m3u8 file. And if didn't resolve the issue maybe you can use some 3rd paty plugins like Vitamio http://vitamio.org/

Answer (score 0):

This is a very interesting question. From your logs, I would like to quote this portion

```
E/OMXNodeInstance( 39): OMX_GetExtensionIndex failed
V/OMXNodeInstance( 39): enableGraphicBuffers at 301 OMX_GetExtensionIndex returned 2147487745
```

These 2 error messages are received during `initNativeWindow` call of the `ACodec` as part of it's transition from `LOADED` to `IDLE` state. From an `OMX` perspective, as part of the `LOADED to IDLE` transition, [`ACodec::LoadedState::onConfigureComponent`](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/ACodec.cpp#3257) is invoked. As part of this function, [`initNativeWindow`](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/ACodec.cpp#3288) is invoked.

In [`initNativeWindow`](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/ACodec.cpp#2065), there are **two** distinct conditions. The first case is when the user has provided a `nativeWindow` or rather a `Surface` or `SurfaceTexture` to the codec to write it's output into. The other case is when the user hasn't provided a `Surface` to the `MediaPlayer` engine.

```
V/ACodec ( 39): onStart
V/ACodec ( 39): [OMX.google.h264.decoder] Now Loaded->Idle
```

From these logs, it can be observed that the return code of `initNativeWindow` is ok which is **only possible** if the control branched to the case where `mNativeNativeWindow` is NULL as observed [here](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/ACodec.cpp#2070). The return code for the `false` case is not caught by the `ACodec` which means that the component transitioned to `IDLE` state successfully.

In a nutshell, the issue is mainly arising due to a `Surface` not being provided to the `MediaPlayer`.

**Some Suggestions:**

Since you are employing `NuPlayer`, I would recommend you to check if [`NuPlayer::setVideoSurfaceTexture`](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libmediaplayerservice/nuplayer/NuPlayer.cpp#143) is called and whether a `non-NULL` object is passed from `NuPlayer` to downstream components.

From a `MediaPlayer` perspective, you should set a surface as part of the `setSurface` call.

In general, you need to provide a `sink` for the video decoder chain.

Answer (score 0):

```
E/OMXNodeInstance( 39): OMX_GetExtensionIndex failed
V/OMXNodeInstance( 39): enableGraphicBuffers at 301 OMX_GetExtensionIndex returned 2147487745
```

the call to **OMX_GetExtensionIndex** lands into SoftOMXComponent([here](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/omx/SoftOMXComponent.cpp)) which is just a stubbed function and always returns **OMX_ErrorUndefined** which leads to failing of **enableGraphicBuffers**