# Stock Android H264 decoder failing on .m3u8 URL files

Tags: android, h.264

I haven't found a solution for HW decoding of m3u8 files (i.e. live streaming), which I've asked about in:

[ACodec call to OMX_GetExtensionIndex fails, during playback of an m3u8 file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167635/acodec-call-to-omx-getextensionindex-fails-during-playback-of-an-m3u8-file)

So, I decided to try forcing the use of stock Google SW decoding for ACodedc:

```
   bool ACodec::UninitializedState::onAllocateComponent
   ...
   OMXCodec::findMatchingCodecs(
            mime.c_str(),
            encoder, // createEncoder
            NULL,  // matchComponentName
            kSoftwareCodecsOnly,  // Forcing SW for ACodec i.e. live streaming
            &matchingCodecs,
            &matchingCodecQuirks);
```

but it crashed... Seems like buffer size (91286) was larger than info->mData->capacity (65536), given on buffer allocation:

```
 V/ACodec  (   74): [OMX.google.h264.decoder] Allocating 8 buffers of size 65536 on input port
```

Buffer size gets from these fragments, in Acodec.cpp:

```
ACodec::setupVideoEncoder
 ...
def.nBufferSize = (video_def->nStride * video_def->nSliceHeight * 3) / 2;

ACodec::setVideoFormatOnPort
...
if (portIndex == kPortIndexInput) {
    // XXX Need a (much) better heuristic to compute input buffer sizes.
    const size_t X = 64 * 1024;
    if (def.nBufferSize < X) {
        def.nBufferSize = X;
    }
}
```

I changed this logic like below, simply doubling size:

```
const size_t X = 128 * 1024;
```

This made it went trough the intial stages of decoding, but it later fails for another reason:

```
V/MediaPlayer( 1040): setDataSource(http://everyrai-lh.akamaihd.net/i/rai_1@177959/master.m3u8)
V/MediaPlayerService(   74): Client(8) constructor
V/MediaPlayerService(   74): Create new client(8) from pid 1040, uid 10064, 
V/MediaPlayerService(   74): setDataSource(http://everyrai-lh.akamaihd.net/i/rai_1@177959/master.m3u8)
...
V/ACodec  (   74): Increasing nBufferSize to 131072
V/ACodec  (   74): setVideoFormatOnPort
V/ACodec  (   74): ComponentName: OMX.google.h264.decoder
V/ACodec  (   74): onStart
V/ACodec  (   74): [OMX.google.h264.decoder] Now Loaded->Idle
V/ACodec  (   74): [OMX.google.h264.decoder] Allocating 8 buffers of size 131072 on input port
V/ACodec  (   74): [OMX.google.h264.decoder] Allocating 2 buffers of size 115200 on output port
V/ACodec  (   74): [OMX.google.h264.decoder] Now Idle->Executing
V/ACodec  (   74): [OMX.google.h264.decoder] calling fillBuffer 0x2a085a80
V/ACodec  (   74): [OMX.google.h264.decoder] calling fillBuffer 0x2a085c58
V/ACodec  (   74): [OMX.google.h264.decoder] Now Executing
V/ACodec  (   74): [OMX.google.h264.decoder] calling emptyBuffer 0x2a089e30 w/ codec specific data
V/ACodec  (   74): [OMX.google.h264.decoder] onOMXEmptyBufferDone 0x2a089e30
V/ACodec  (   74): [OMX.google.h264.decoder] calling emptyBuffer 0x2a099d50 w/ codec specific data
V/ACodec  (   74): [OMX.google.h264.decoder] calling emptyBuffer 0x2a089e30 w/ time 240000 us
E/SoftAVC (   74): Decoder failed: -2
V/ACodec  (   74): [OMX.google.h264.decoder] onOMXEmptyBufferDone 0x2a099d50
V/ACodec  (   74): [OMX.google.h264.decoder] calling emptyBuffer 0x2a099c50 w/ time 360000 us
E/ACodec  (   74): [OMX.google.h264.decoder] ERROR(0x80001001)
...
```

Adding some trace logs in h264dec/source, I got these additional info:

```
D/H264Dec (   75): H264SwDecInit#
D/H264Dec (   75): H264SwDecInit# decInst 0x2a075448 noOutputReordering 0
D/H264Dec (   75): H264SwDecInit# OK: return 0x2a0758a8
D/H264Dec (   75): H264SwDecDecode#
D/H264Dec (   75): H264SwDecDecode# decInst 0x2a0758a8  pInput 0x42b6dd88  pOutput 0x42b6dd7c
D/H264Dec (   75): H264SwDecDecode# OK: DecResult 1
D/H264Dec (   75): H264SwDecDecode#
D/H264Dec (   75): H264SwDecDecode# decInst 0x2a0758a8  pInput 0x42b6dd88  pOutput 0x42b6dd7c
D/H264Dec (   75): H264SwDecDecode# OK: DecResult 1
D/H264Dec (   75): H264SwDecDecode#
D/H264Dec (   75): H264SwDecDecode# decInst 0x2a0758a8  pInput 0x42b6dd88  pOutput 0x42b6dd7c
D/H264Dec (   75): H264SwDecDecode# OK: DecResult -2
E/SoftAVC (   75): Decoder failed: -2
I/SoftAAC2(   75): Reconfiguring decoder: 44100 Hz, 2 channels
E/ACodec  (   75): [OMX.google.h264.decoder] ERROR(0x80001001)
E/NuPlayer(   75): Received error from video decoder, aborting playback.
```

Here, the "DecResult -2" is H264SWDEC_STRM_ERR from this fragment of code:

```
    decResult = h264bsdDecode(&pDecCont->storage, tmpStream, strmLen,
    ...
    switch (decResult)
    {
    ...
        case H264BSD_PARAM_SET_ERROR:
            if ( !h264bsdCheckValidParamSets(&pDecCont->storage) &&
                 strmLen == 0 )
            {
                returnValue = H264SWDEC_STRM_ERR;
```

I wonder, first of all, why the stock decoder doesn't work Out-of-the-Box, with standard streaming URLs (the underlying app works on other devices).

Was my guess about buffer "resizing" correct? I don't know why it failed, with the default sizing logic.

Any suggestion / fix with respect to latest error?

Could it be related to the size error above?

thanks
Fabio

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to do with the size hack above... The very first error I get is:

```
E/H264_pps(   75): entropy_coding_mode_flag
E/H264_decoder(   75): PIC_PARAM_SET
```

which is from this code fragment in h264bsd_pic_param_set.c:

```
/* entropy_coding_mode_flag, shall be 0 for baseline profile */
tmp = h264bsdGetBits(pStrmData, 1);
if (tmp)
{
    EPRINT("entropy_coding_mode_flag");
    return(HANTRO_NOK);
}
```

Looking in H264 docs, I found out that entropy_coding_mode_flag determines two types of encoding:

```
CAVLC: Context-based adaptive variable-length coding
CABAC: Context-based adaptive binary arithmetic coding
```

Out of the the two, CAVLC is the lower-quality, easier-to-decode option, while CABAC is the higher-quality, harder-to-decode option.

See more at:

http://www.streaminglearningcenter.com/articles/producing-h264-video-for-flash-an-overview.html?page=3#sthash.26PqYA7p.dpuf

Seems like only the "baseline profile" is supported by AOSP decoder, while here we have a stream encoded with entropy_coding_mode_flag set (i.e. CABAC).

That might be the same reason the HW decoder doesn't work either - it doesn't support CABAC H264.

A possible solution, might come from using a different SW codec, e.g. the open "ffmpeg" ones, which seems to be working just fine, playing exactly the same stream through the MXPlayer app. What I'd like is to have these codecs also being used by the stock player.

These patches (to be merged in JB), integrating ffmpeg codec in AOSP, might be doing the trick:

https://github.com/omxcodec/stagefright-plugins (Code)

Though it's yet to be applied and tested...